# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataframe as such:

```
df
           ID           val1     Param  val2   
0        0.0000        -0.7110  'A'   2.5 
1        0.0000        -0.7285  'A'   2.0 
2        0.0000        -0.4867  'B'   2.3 
3        0.0000        -0.5729  'C'   2.2 ...   
91296    0.0485         0.0733  'Y'   2.1 
91297    0.0485        -0.2035  'Y'   2.24 
91298    0.0485        -0.0479  'Z'   2.5
```

I'm trying to run a loop where I print a plot for each id+param
appended to a list, then save the plots to their associated folders in
a directory.

Desired:

`p = []
test = df.groupby(ID) for all IDs in test:
     for all unique params:
         p.append(create plot per id and associated param)`

And this is desired output:

Folder(0.0000)

```
     --> 'A'.png
     --> 'B'.png
     --> 'C'.png
```

Folder(0.0485)

```
     --> 'Y'.png
     --> 'Z'.png
```

This is what I have so far:

```
final_gr = df.groupby('ID') for j in final_gr.groups:
     df_slice = df[df['ID'] == j]
     p.append(ggplot(aes('val1','val2'), data = df_slice) + \
     geom_point(color='c') + ggtitle(element_text(text='Val1 vs %s\nat ID:
 %s'%(str(df_slice.Param.unique())[2:-2],str(df_slice.ID.unique())),size=15,face='bold'))
 + \
     theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(name='%s'%str(df_slice.Param.unique())))
     for img in p:
         img.save(r'\DIRECTORY\%s\%s.png'%(str(df_slice.ID.unique())[2:-2],df_slice.Param.unique()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Just added three more lines to jfbeltran's code, where I first (externally in a previous step) extracted the Param names by ID to their respective text files, checked if the Param was in the text file by ID, then created a new dataframe with matching Param and ID:

```
for key, group in df.groupby(by='ID'):
for g in group.Param.unique():
    if g in open('%s.txt'%str(key)).read():
        df_slice = group[(group['ID'] == key) & (group['Param'] == g)]
        p.append(ggplot(aes('Val1','Val2'), data = df_slice) + \
        geom_point(color='c') + ggtitle(element_text(text='Val1 vs %s\nat ID:%s'%(str(g),
        str(key)),size=15,face='bold'))+ \
        theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(name='%s'%str(g)))
        for img in p:
            #os.mkdir(r'DIRECTORY\%s'%key)
            img.save(r'DIRECTORY\%s\%s.png'%(str(key),str(g)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing up some core python formatting here. You're probably looking for something more like this.

```
import os
for key, group in df.groupby(by='ID'):
    p.append(ggplot(aes('val1','val2'), data = group) + \ 
    geom_point(color='c') + ggtitle(element_text(text='Val1 vs %s\nat ID:
    %s'%(str(group.Param.unique())
    [2:-2],str(key)),size=15,face='bold'))
    + \
    theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(name='%s'%str(group.Param.unique())))
    for img in p:
        os.mkdir(r'\DIRECTORY\%s'%key)
        img.save(r'\DIRECTORY\%s\%s.png'(str(key[2:-2],df_slice.Param.unique()))
```

Note that you might want to make the directory you're writing to, as it will not be created automatically for you if it doesn't exist. (see os.mkdir)

I suggest you check out the key, group for loop results using a simple loop first like so:

```
for key, group in df.groupby(by='ID'):
    print key

for key, group in df.groupby(by='ID'):
    print group
```

Comment: Still experiencing error: No such file or directory: "C:\\DIRECTORY\\0.0000\\['A'\n 'B'\n 'C'\n ... .png]. I tried adding another for loop like: 'for g in group.Param.unique()' right after the first for loop you provided, and it would sort of work, but it was outputting exactly the same plot for every param name. They should all be different and be plotted by group ID.

Comment: Fixed it. Just added three more lines to your code, where I first (externally in a previous step) extracted the Param names by ID to their respective text files, checked if the Param was in the text file by ID, then created a new dataframe with matching Param and ID: for key, group in complete.groupby(by='ID'):
    for g in group.Param.unique():
        if g in open('%s.txt'%str(key)).read():
            df_slice = group[(group['ID'] == key) & (group['Param'] == g)]